# Empty Content-Type in curl_easy_perform GET request

Tags: libcurl

Kindly disregard this issue, the problems seems to lie in `werkzeug`.

I believe I have detected a problem with **Content-Type** for GET requests sent using `curl_easy_perform`, in libcurl version 7.29 (CentOS 7).
The problem is that the HTTP header **Content-Type** is present (with empty value) in the request:

```
Content-Type:
```

In Ubuntu 18.04, with libcurl 7.58, this problem doesn't occur (as expected the header is not present in the request). I've searched Changlogs but without finding anything about this assumed fix. I did find some mention of the very same bug fixed in the PHP-curl library.

So, my question is simply: is it true that this behaviour has been fixed somewhere between 7.29 and 7.58 ?

I just made a test implementation, as short as possible, to see the problem.
This is the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>         // fprintf, ...                                                                       
#include <stdlib.h>        // exit                                                                               
#include <curl/curl.h>     // curl                                                                               
#include <curl/curlver.h>  // VERSION                                                                            

int main(int argC, char* argV[])
{
  CURL*     curlP;
  CURLcode  cc;

  printf("curl version: %s\n", LIBCURL_VERSION);

  curlP = curl_easy_init();

  if (curlP == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_init failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(cc));
    exit(1);
  }

  curl_easy_setopt(curlP, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost:1028/accumulate");
  cc = curl_easy_perform(curlP);

  if (cc != CURLE_OK)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(cc));
    exit(2);
  }

  curl_easy_cleanup(curlP);

  return 0;
}
```

The code is edited in a file called `get.c` and I compile it like this:

```
gcc get.c -o get -lcurl
```

The test runs in CentOS 7 with libcurl 7.58 (that I installed manually under /usr/local).

I have a simple test program, an accumulator, written in python, listening to port 1028, recording all requests that enters, and that spits it out on receiving a request with the URL path `/dump`.

Here is the entire sequence:

```
kz@centos7:curlTest> gcc get.c -o get -lcurl
kz@centos7:curlTest> ./get
curl version: 7.58.0
kz@centos7:curlTest> curl localhost:1028/dump
GET http://localhost:1028/accumulate
Content-Length: 
Host: localhost:1028
Accept: */*
Content-Type: 
=======================================
kz@centos7:curlTest>
```

As can be seen in this test, the GET request (sent by `get` to the accumulator) includes HTTP headers `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` without value.

The exact same test in Ubuntu 18.04 looks like this:

```
kz@xps:libcurlTest> gcc get.c -o get -lcurl
kz@xps:libcurlTest> ./get
curl version: 7.58.0
kz@xps:libcurlTest> curl localhost:1028/dump
GET http://localhost:1028/accumulate
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:1028
=======================================
kz@xps:libcurlTest>
```

Note the absence of `Content-Length`and `Content-Type`.

Before implementing this little test program, I made numerous attempts to avoid the `Content-Type`, by setting it in its slist to "Content-Type:", without space, with one space and with two spaces after the colon. I also tried without colon and of course without adding it to the slist (in which case it comes with the default content-type). I also tried to tell libcurl that the request is a GET, don't remember the details of that call right now.

Now, the error is probably mine, as I have very little experience using libcurl. It's just strange that all is OK in Ubuntu but not in CentOS ...

Comment: I think I have the same problem with libcurl version 7.38.0. Maybe the fix is in a version newer than that.

Comment: You don't show any code. I don't recognize this as a known problem of any old libcurl.

Comment: The code is pretty complex and I'd need to spend quite some time to shorten it enough for display here. It is the exact same code in Ubuntu though, where the problem does not occur. I will implement a tiny test from scratch and if I see the same problem I will have some code to display

Comment: Finally the problem seems to lie in a bug in `werkzeug`, a python library used by flask that is used by the accumulator. Very sorry for the noise :(